# LightOpenID Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:4016:804::2004: Network is unreachable

Tags: php, mysql, openid, lightopenid

I'm playing around with LightOpenID library on a free web host (awspace) and so far all my attempts to log in via google account using open id result in the following error :

example-google.php:

> Failed to connect to 2a00:1450:4016:804::2004: Network is unreachable

And I'm not really sure what's the cause so I would love to hear some suggestions since all I can think of is that it could be related to the free webhost plan (i.e., I have to setup my own) ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue : the host doesn't support curl operations :)